# Is there a term for a function that modifies its arguments?

Tags: function, computer-science, pass-by-reference

I'm not really classically educated in CS or mathematics. I'm just thinking there should be a term for this in pass-by-reference laungauges such as php. IE. functions that return a result (like how you'd want most functions to work) versus functions that modify an in-parameter.
Is there such a term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only term that I have heard relating to what you are talking about is: *parameter idempotence*

Simply put this type of function guarantees that the arguments remain untouched.

As far as a function that changes parameters I haven't heard any particular terms but I just say: *parameter mutating*.

From my experience any function that takes a reference to an object, it's a fairly safe bet that it will be mutating that parameter in some way.

Comment: yeah that makes sense, i guess i mean non-object variables, like arrays/strings etc